# Generate multiple ActiveRecord model objects for each hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

I'm making a web app for a reservation system where the user can chose the hour, but in every hour can be occupied by max 4 users.
I have a model called Hours and in his controller i show a fullcalendar but only displays the reserved hours and i want to show every hour with a link to new reservation model.

I tough i could create Hours whit this method but it seems that doesnt work

```
def horas_libres



  t1 = DateTime.now.beginning_of_hour() + 2.hours
  t2 = t1 + 1.months
  @hora = Hora.new()

  (t1 .. t2).step(1.hours) do |h|
    @hora = Hora.new()
    @hora.inicio = h
    @hora.fin = (h + 1.hours)
    @hora.cable_id = 1
    @hora.plazas = 0

    if Hora.where(inicio: @hora.inicio).nil? then
      @hora.save
    end

  end  

  @horas = Hora.all
end
```

I dont know if it's the best way to do it so if anyone has any suggestion or a correction to make the method works it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Here is the hour migration

```
class CreateHoras < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :horas do |t|
  t.datetime :inicio, :null => false
  t.datetime :fin, :null => false
  t.integer :horainicio, :null => false, :default => 10
  t.integer :horafin, :null => false, :default => 22
  t.references :cable, index: true, :null => false
  t.integer :plazas, :null => false, :default => 0
  t.string :titulo, :null => false, :default => "Libre"
  t.string :color, :null => false, :default => "Green"
  t.boolean :activo, :null => false, :default => true

  t.timestamps
end

 add_index :horas, :inicio, :unique => true
 add_index :horas, :fin, :unique => true
end
end
```

Comment: Please show us the migration used to create the Hour model. BTW, this is not a good idea.

Comment: @Chandranshu i added the migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need the `Hora` model. You can do everything in the `Reservation` model since rails has built in functions to handle Time.

In your `Reservation` model you can have a column named `date_of_reservation` and you could also have a custom validation method that checks the database for the count of reservation within the hour of `date_of_reservation`. If the count is more than 4, it adds an error which prevents the user from creating a new reservation.

Comment: i have that column but i created the Horas model to show all the hours free or reserved in the fullcalendar and i cant think in another solution

Comment: You can accomplish that in the views and do not need a `Hora` model. In your index you can have a loop over the hours and see if the size of reservations is less than 4. Check group by in this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Comment: yes, that works with reserved hours, but with this method i cant show the free hours because there is no reservations. (I want to achieve something like this [link](http://www.reservatucable.com/web/reserva/calendario/centro/1)

Comment: Why not? If you have more than 4 reservations you show a `<td>Reservado</td>`, if not you show `<td><%= link_to 'libre', new_reservation_path(time)%></td>` and you use the `params[:time]` to set the time of reservation in your `new` action

Comment: a loop like the date.step i posted above?